# In Java how do I create a structured tree using FileVisitor

Tags: java, tree, guava, filevisitor, j2html

Given a starting path I want to create a tree like object representing the filesystem using Java, **showing all the folders down to level x but not ordinary files.** . So using *FileVisitor* I know that every time just before Im going to browse a new subfolder that the *preVisitDirectory()* method will be called and once it had completed parsing all its children the *postVisitDirectory()* will be called, but my problem is knowing how to attach this directory to its parent.

i.e in my case I want to create data for jstree using ul/li/ul/li elements, and Im doing this with [j2html](https://j2html.com/) lib. So create root using ul(), then when I go into preVisitDirectory() I would create a li() element and in postVisitDirectory() would want to attach to ul() using ul().with(li) but I cant see how to keep track of where I am in building my tree.

e.g static hard coded example not actually browsing tree

```
public Tag createBrowseTreeAsHtml()
    {
        Tag ulTag = ul(
                li("ChildNode 2").withId("child_node_1"),
                li("ChildNode")
        );

        Tag divTag= div(
                    ul(
                        li("Root Node 1").with(ulTag),
                        li("Root Node 2")
                    )
                )
                .withId("jstree");
        return div().with(divTag);
    }
```

I see Guava has support for  [Graphs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained), should I be utilising this somehow ?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what you're looking to achieve. I understand that you want to interact with a filesystem and do something with j2html, but I do not understand yet what the connection between the two is and why you want to do all of this. Can you clarify?

Comment: Im creating a webpage with j2html that forms part of a we application, and this particular component will allow user to select a folder on the server because the idea is that the user can then access the server folders remotely via their browser (on phone/ipad etc). The j2html is rendering html that is understood by Jstree.

Comment: Actually things have moved on from this since Im now wanting to generate json data for use by jstree, so j2html is irrevelant. So I have already got something working but its seems very inefficient. I use FileVisitor to traverse tree and put all the folders found into a Set, I then use another class to convert that set into a recursive structure comprising node and children, (and then another class to convert this to json). It seems I should be able to combine first and second steps but I cannot see how.

Comment: It sounds to me then that this problem might be better solved using graphs, like how you suggested in your OP. Try using Guava's `Graph` class, modelling each folder as a node, and putting directed edges between each folder and its children folders.