# Can I use jsTree preloaded with JSON data and also use Ajax

Tags: json, ajax, jstree

I have jsTree working with JSON data: the JSON data represents the server's file system, and the user can select a folder from the tree, which is then added to the folder input field). I don't want the page to load without the top three levels of the file system provided. However, I don't parse the whole file system because that would take too long.

Can I pre-populate jsTree with JSON data and use Ajax when the user opens nodes further down the tree which were not pre-populated, or do I have to use Ajax for the initial load as well?

Below I show my current code (without any Ajax), but only retrieving data down to one level for the sake of brevity: it returns `C:\` and `E:\` file systems from the server. This works, but I'm unclear how to introduce Ajax to this when the user tries to open a node further down the hierarchy.

```
    <label for="folder">Selected Folder</label>
    <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder">
    <br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function createJSTree(jsondata) 
    {            
      $('#jstree').jstree(
        {
          "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","cookie"],
          'core': 
          {
              'data': jsondata
          }
        }
      )
      .bind("select_node.jstree",   
                function (e, data) 
                {
                    var objNode = data.instance.get_node(data.selected);
                    document.getElementById('folder').value=objNode.id;
                }
        )
      ;
    }

    $(function() { var jsondata ={"text":"pclaptop","children":[{"id":"C:\\","text":"C:\\","children":[]},{"id":"E:\\","text":"E:\\","children":[]}]}; createJSTree(jsondata); })
    </script>
```

Comment: what version of jsTree are you using?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin The latest I think, 3.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into the ajax piece of the code I had to set the [check_callback parameter in jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/docs/interaction/) it enables editing of the jsTree. Next, I call `$('#jstree').jstree().create_node('#', parsedData, "last"); in the success method of jQuery's ajax call, and that did the trick. My solution is below:

index.html

```
<label for="folder">Selected Folder</label>
    <input type="text" name="folder" id="folder">
    <br>
    <button id="create-node-button">
       Create Node
    </button>
<div id="jstree"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createJSTree(jsondata) {
        $('#jstree').jstree({
                "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "cookie"],
                'core': {
                    'check_callback': true,
                    'data': jsondata
                }
            })
            .bind("select_node.jstree",
                function(e, data) {
                    var objNode = data.instance.get_node(data.selected);
                    document.getElementById('folder').value = objNode.id;
                }
            );
    }

    $(function() {
        var jsondata = [{
                "id": "pclaptop",
                "parent": "#",
                "text": "pclaptop"
            },
            {
                "id": "C:\\",
                "parent": "pclaptop",
                "text": "C:\\"
            },
            {
                "id": "E:\\",
                "parent": "pclaptop",
                "text": "E:\\"
            },
            {
                "id": "F:\\",
                "parent": "pclaptop",
                "text": "F:\\"
            }
        ];
        createJSTree(jsondata);

        $("#create-node-button").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./data.json",
                success: function(data){
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    $('#jstree').jstree().create_node('#', parsedData, "last");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

data.json

```
{ "id" : "ajson5", "text" : "newly added" }
```

Lastly, [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/74xmw78b/7/) . I wasn't sure of how to properly set up the ajax call in jsfiddle so I did it locally instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but I want it to open the contents of a node when you click on the node not on a separate button, and from the users point of view it is not creating data  simply retrieving the data from the server as necessary instead of trying to retrieve in all in one go. Looking at another application that does this I may have misled you, it seems there should be little white arrow to the left of each children and it would be on clicking this to open it that should invoke the ajax call.

Comment: Understood; the button will be an easy fix. However, I'm not sure what you're expecting with regard to the server functionality which is why that part was hard-coded in the json file. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Server functionality is not really the issue,it should provide the correct json for the the tree node that has been clicked, but I can do that.  My problem is configured the jstree code correctly so that it calls the server (or mockup) and uses the data returned.

Comment: Ok, I removed the button and  updated my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/74xmw78b/15/. I will update my answer in a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was very helpful but I have since discovered that although the jstree website is not that helpful the README in the jstree github repo https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-a-tree-using-an-array-or-json has very good explanation of lazy load ajax, so i have created a simpler solution based on that and wil post an answer in due cause, but will award you the bounty for your help.